# how to impliment notification in cordova app which uses firebase as server or database

Tags: cordova, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I need to implement the notification when the cordova app is not even when the app is in the cache.
What should be done and from where to start.
I don't get any idea how does it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) which brings push notifications, analytics, event tracking, crash reporting and more from Google Firebase to your Cordova project.

Install the plugin by adding it your project's config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="0.1.19" />
```

or by running:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase@0.1.19 --save
```

Download your Firebase configuration files, GoogleService-Info.plist for ios and google-services.json for android, and place them in the root folder of your cordova project:

```
- My Project/
    platforms/
    plugins/
    www/
    config.xml
    google-services.json       <--
    GoogleService-Info.plist   <--
    ...
```

Check this [support page](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592) for details on how to download the files from firebase.

Check the link above and this [link](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm) for more information.